# Как проверить установилась ли Java на Win10 корректно?

Tags: java

При установке Java полностью на диск D устанавливаю переменные **Path** `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin` но в CMD при запросе D: `javac` или D: programms - `javac` пишет, что не является пакетным или системным файлом.

Далее, при попытке копировании всех папок Java на диск С в Program Files и изменением переменных, удалив папку Java на диске D- также при запросе С: javac C: Program Files javac - то же самое т. е. находит только при конкретных запросах как и в начале установки D: programms\Java\jdk\bin\javac и сейчас С: Program Files\Java\jdk\bin\javac  Корректна ли такая установка сейчас?

[image: скрин]

В конце этого скрина - правильно ли расположены записи? Может быть, стоит их писать отдельно на 2-х строках для jdk и jre?

И как лучше указать эти пути, возможно ли устанавливать на диск D вообще, чтобы потом установить IDE NetBeans 8.2? там для установки IDE требуется комплект Java SE (JDK) 8

Comment: удал все полность. начни установку JDK, во время установки укажи путь

Comment: всё полностью удалил, реестр почистил, но папка Java на диске D в которой jdk не удаляется никак. Сейчас пробую перенести все файлы с D на С и отформатировать диск D может получится удалить её. не совсем понятно:какой путь указывать при установке?   такой? C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin  чтобы IDE норм работал?

Comment: Вообще-то да, десятка должна была показать в двух строках...